# Django Dynamic Form Field - how to change?

Tags: django, django-forms

In my Django form below

```
class Form_Vechicle(forms.ModelForm):
    flatno_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
        required=True, help_text="Select flat No from the list", empty_label="Select flat no",
        queryset=FlatNo.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).order_by("flatindex"),
        label="Flat No")

    reg_no = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
        required=True, min_length=2, max_length=15, help_text="Regtration No", label="Veh No")

    detail = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
        required=True, max_length=25, help_text="make/modal",
        label="Brand")


    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['flatno_id', 'reg_no', 'detail' ]
```

how do I change form field widget dynamically based on user login type

No change in this form if user is superuser.

For all other user (non superuser), I would like to hide the flatno_id field

```
flatno_id = widgets.HiddenInput()
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this method to hide or show the a field in model form

```
class Form_Vechicle(forms.ModelForm):
    flatno_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
        required=True, help_text="Select flat No from the list", empty_label="Select flat no",
        queryset=FlatNo.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).order_by("flatindex"),
        label="Flat No")

    reg_no = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
        required=True, min_length=2, max_length=15, help_text="Regtration No", label="Veh No")

    detail = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}),
        required=True, max_length=25, help_text="make/modal",
        label="Brand")


    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['flatno_id', 'reg_no', 'detail' ]
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if !(request.user.is_superuser):
            self.fields['flatno_id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can overload **init** of you form

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if IF_CASE:
        self.fields['flatno_id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```